# Mosby interfaces MvpView and MvpPresenter are not visible, version 3.1.0

Tags: java, android, mosby

I have an Android project, Java language and Gradle. I am trying to use Mosby-Conductor libraries, therefore I have imported next libraries:

```
compile 'com.bluelinelabs:conductor:2.1.4'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp:3.1.0'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-conductor:3.1.0'
```

However, **MvpView** and **MvpPresenter** interfaces are not visible in my project, **I cannot implement them**. Those ones are not comming inside the classes of the libraries. Those classes are inside mvp-common module (https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/tree/master/mvp-common), but that jar is not imported. I tried adding that module as a dependency as well but it did not help:

```
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-common:3.1.0'
```

Have anyone had this same issue at all ?

Comment: hm, this sounds wired... Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: Clean it, re-build it, remove/include dependency ... Did not work. I just did what annoyingly almost always work, I restarted Android Studio and magic happened, mvp-common jar is imported now. Closing the question, thanks for quick answer. Nice lib, btw. @sockeqwe